# Using Recursive with CTE in SQL Query vs. Recursive in C#

Tags: c#, sql, recursion, optimization

I have been researching which approach will better optimize my system whether it is to use Recursive in my Stored Procedure (SQL) or to use Recursive in the C#.

I have read two points of view where one explained that using recursive in c# is more complex and slower but solved using a *tail-call optimization* but C# does not support this.

On the other hand, I have read a thread where it is used in their program written in C# to reduce the Database burden.

I want to know which one is better in a system that'll store and retrieve thousands of records.

Comment: The sql language is not well suited to use recursion.  Recursion in c# is not very complex.  The issue is the amount of data being transferred between the database and the c# and the number of queries needed to complete the recursion.  If you can query the database once and retrieve all the data (the amount of data doesn't give memory issues in c#) then I recommend putting data in to a c# datatable (using an adapter).  Then do the recursion in c#.

Comment: Thanks! I have been putting data in an IEnumerable instead of a DataTable though. I wonder which one is better?

Comment: I like datatable better because I can do in one instruction using an adapter.  To create an IEnumerable you would need to use a datareader and a loop.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are better off writing a *single* query and avoiding the overhead of going back-and-forth to the database.

You haven't specified what you are trying to do.  But I would expect a recursive CTE to work better in the database rather than in the application for the following reasons:

- You don't have the overhead of multiple calls to the database.
- The intermediate results can be saved in internal database format.
- You don't have to return data to the application and passing it back into the database.

In addition, some things that you might approach using recursion in C# might be better implemented using SQL constructs, such as window functions.